# SSIS package throws errors in SQL server agent job

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ssis

I have a simple SSIS package that runs fine from Visual Studio copying/formatting Excel worksheets.  However, when I try to run this package from a SQL Server agent job it fails on my VB.NET script in the package.  This is all on the same server, and being ran with the same account.

The SQL agent error message is: 
Code: 0x000000001 
Source: VB script step
Description: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Visual Studio 2010,
Server 2012 R2,
Sql Server 2012 SP2,
Excel 2013

Comment: Something is not the same. Try using error handling block in the VB script and write the inner exception to a table.

Comment: There is not enough information in the question for anyone to help you.   Getting the inner exception would help, and seeing the code of VB Script Step might also be necessary.

Comment: Was an permissions issue within the script.  Apparently even with setting up a proxy to run the job, the VB script task in my SSIS package is still being ran be the SQL Agent account.